# How to copy Java object without a change to the original affecting the copy

Tags: java, linked-list, copy, copy-constructor

In the function addStartNode, I create a new Node 'temp' whose value is set to equal that of 'head'. Then I set head to be a new Node with value different 'v'.

However, when I print both the values for 'temp' and 'head', it displays the same thing.

I've tried many different approaches to this, including a copy constructor, but it doesn't seem to be changing anything.

Any help would be great!

```
public class DoublyLinkedList {

    private static class Node {

        private static int value;

        Node(int v) {
            value = v;
        }

        int getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }

    private static Node head;

    void addStartNode(int v) {
        if (head == null) {
            head = new Node(v);
        } else {
            Node temp = new Node(head.getValue());
            PRINT VALUES HERE
            head = new Node(v);
            PRINT VALUES HERE
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared `value` as `static` in the Node class.

If the attribute is static then it is shared by all instances of Node.

Change :

```
private static int value;
```

To

```
private int value;
```

Imagine you change your code to this one :

```
static class Node {

    private static int nbOfNode = 0;
    private int value;

    Node(int v) {
        nbOfNode++;
        value = v;
    }

    int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    static int getNbOfNode() {
        return nbOfNode;
    }
}
```

Now `value` is not static then each instance of Node will have its proper value.

On the other hand
`nbOfNode` is static then it will be shared among all the instances of the Node class, because it is a class level variable.

Now if you run this:

```
Node n1 = new Node(11);
System.out.println(n1.getValue());
System.out.println(Node.getNbOfNode());
Node n2 = new Node(22);
System.out.println(n2.getValue());
System.out.println(Node.getNbOfNode());
```

It will produce :

> 11 - the proper value of the node n1
>
> 1 - the incremented shared value
>
> 22 - the proper value of the node n2
>
> 2 - the second increment of the shared value

During the instantiation of n2 the constructor will increment the same variable than the one previously incremented by the instantiation of n1

Comment: Great that sorted it! I thought I understood static variables, I guess not. Can you explain why that works?

Comment: @numberjak A static field is one value shared by all instances of the enclosing class (in this case, `DoublyLinkedList.Node`).  A non-static field means each instance of the enclosing class gets its own independent value.

Comment: @numberjak just put a small example in my answer